# R.NET Web application R library load

Tags: c#, r, r.net

I have two applications: (A) is a console app, (B) is an MVC web app.
Both x64, both have same Nuget references to R.

Both run the same lines of code:

```
        var engine = REngine.GetInstance();

        engine.Evaluate("log.ir <- log(iris[, 1:4])");
        engine.Evaluate("ir.species <- iris[, 5]");

        engine.Evaluate("ir.pca <- stats:::prcomp(log.ir, center = TRUE, scale = TRUE)");
```

*The "stats:::" is telling the namespace of the function.

Now, the console app executes the code and is working absolutely fine. Web app - doesnt, it fails with the following error:

[image]

Ive tried running in 32 bit - made no difference.
Ive checked all R related global variables (R_USER, R_ARCH, R_HOME, R_LIBS_USER) - they are the same when running both apps.

Anyone got any suggestions what going on ?!

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

After manually adding the path to R library to PATH and Path environment variables, it fixed the problem.

Ref: [here](https://rdotnet.codeplex.com/workitem/117)